# How does the queue in Pytorch DataLoader work with num_workers >= 2?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

Do I understand the following correctly?

When `num_workers >=1`, the main process pre-loads `prefetch_factor * num_workers` batches. When the training loop consumes one batch, the corresponding worker loads the next batch in its queue.

If this is the case, let's go through an example.

*NOTE: I have chosen the numeric values for illustration purposes and*
*have ignored various overheads in this example. The accompanying code example uses these numbers.*

Say I have `num_workers=4`,  `prefetch_factor=4`,  `batch_size=128`. Further assume, it takes `0.003125 s` to fetch an item from a source database and the train step takes `0.05 s`.

Now, each batch would take `0.003125 * 128 = 0.4 s` to load.

With a `prefetch_factor=4` and `num_workers=4`, first, `4*4=16` batches will be loaded.

Once the `16` batches are loaded, the first train step consumes 1 batch and takes `0.05 s`. Say `worker[0]` provided this batch and will start the process to generate a new batch to replenish the queue. Recall fetching a new batch takes `0.4 s`.

Similarly, the second step consumes one more batch and the corresponding worker (`worker[1]` in this example) starts the data fetching process.

The first 8 train steps would take `0.05*8=0.4s`. By this time, `8` batches have been
consumed and `worker[0]` has produced 1 batch. In the next step, 1 batch is consumed and `worker[1]` produces a new batch. `worker[1]` had started the data fetching process in the second train step which would now be completed.

Following this we can see, each subsequent train step will consume 1 batch and one of the workers will produce 1 batch, keeping the dataloader queue to have always `8` batches. This means that the train step is never waiting for the data loading process as there are always 8 batches in the buffer.

I would expect this behavior regardless of the data size of the batch given `num_workers`, `prefetch_factor` are large enough. However, in the following code example that is not case.

In the code below, I define a custom iterable that returns a numpy array. As the size of the numpy array increases, increasing `num_worker` or 'prefetch_factor' does not improve the time taken for running through a batch.

I'm guessing this is because each worker serializes the batch to send to the main process where it is de-serialized. As the data size increase, this process would take more time. However, I would think if the queue size is large enough (`num_workers`, `prefetch_factor`), at some point, there should be a break even point where each training step consumption of a batch would be accompanied by replenishment via one of the workers as I illustrated in the above example.

In the code below, when `MyIterable` returns a small object (np array of size (10, 150)), increasing `num_workers` helps as expected. But when the returned object is larger (np array of size (1000, 150)), `num_workers` or `prefetch_factor` does not do much.

```
# small np object
avg time per batch for num workers=0: 0.47068126868714444
avg time per batch for num workers=2: 0.20982365206225495
avg time per batch for num workers=4: 0.10560789656221914
avg time per batch for num workers=6: 0.07202646931250456
avg time per batch for num workers=8: 0.05311137337469063
```

```
# large np object
avg time per batch for num workers=0: 0.6090951558124971
avg time per batch for num workers=2: 0.4594530961876444
avg time per batch for num workers=4: 0.45023533212543043
avg time per batch for num workers=6: 0.3830978863124983
avg time per batch for num workers=8: 0.3811495694375253
```

Am I missing something here? Why doesn't the data loader queue have enough buffer such that data loading is not the bottleneck?

Even if the serialization and de-serialization process would take longer for the latter case, I'd expect to have a large enough buffer where the consumption and replenishment rate of the batches are almost equal. Otherwise, what is the point of having `prefetch_factor`.

If the code is behaving as expected, are there any other ways to pre-load the next `n` batches in a buffer such that it is large enough and never depleted?

Thanks

```
import time
import torch
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, IterableDataset


def collate_fn(records):
    # some custom collation function
    return records


class MyIterable(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.i = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.i < self.n:
            sleep(0.003125)  # simulates data fetch time
            # return np.random.random((10, 150))  # small data item
            return np.random.random((1000, 150))  # large data item
        else:
            raise StopIteration


class MyIterableDataset(IterableDataset):
    def __init__(self, n):
        super(MyIterableDataset).__init__()
        self.n = n

    def __iter__(self):
        return MyIterable(self.n)


def get_performance_metrics(num_workers):
    ds = MyIterableDataset(n=10000)

    if num_workers == 0:
        dl = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(ds, num_workers=0, batch_size=128, collate_fn=collate_fn)
    else:
        dl = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(ds, num_workers=num_workers, prefetch_factor=4, persistent_workers=True,
                                         batch_size=128, collate_fn=collate_fn,
                                         multiprocessing_context='spawn')
    warmup = 5
    times = []
    t0 = time.perf_counter()
    for i, batch in enumerate(dl):
        sleep(0.05)  # simulates train step
        e = time.perf_counter()
        if i >= warmup:
            times.append(e - t0)
        t0 = time.perf_counter()
        if i >= 20:
            break
    print(f'avg time per batch for num workers={num_workers}: {sum(times) / len(times)}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_worker_options = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
    for n in num_worker_options:
        get_performance_metrics(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

> [...] MyIterable returns a small object [...], increasing num_workers helps as expected. But when the returned object is larger [...], num_workers or prefetch_factor does not do much.[...] Am I missing something here?

Yes. You are not considering that the "constant" overhead involved in inter-process communication scales with the message length (aka `batch_size`). The larger the array you send around, the longer it takes to pickle, transfer, and unpickle the prepared batch. The overhead is independent of the dataset (number of examples/batches), so we often think of it as a constant, but that doesn't mean that the overhead doesn't change when hyperparameters change.

In both of your tests the per-batch time decreases as you increase the worker count. You simply hit diminishing returns sooner for the large array case, because the data being sent around is larger.

> Why doesn't the data loader queue have enough buffer such that data loading is not the bottleneck?

Because the queue's max-size is independent of the rate at which the queue is read from or written to. No matter how large the bucket of water, if its holes are larger than the hose refilling it, the bucket will eventually be empty.

To avoid being bound by loading/preprocessing you need to increase `num_workers` until the effective latency of the input pipeline is smaller than the processing time of one batch. I.e., if (ignoring randomness and locking) `gpu_latency > preprocessing_latency / num_workers` holds you won't face a bottleneck as long as your queue can hold `num_workers + 1` batches.

In practice, however, you may not be able to overcome the bottleneck even if you have enough CPU cores available. This is because (at least in Python, the C++ API may be different) torch uses a naive (lock-based) multi-processing implementation. More workers spawned, means more workers competing for the privilege to send data back to the main thread, aka. they wait to acquire the write lock. As such, you will see diminishing returns with increasing worker count, which may make it impossible to satisfy the above relationship in practice.

> Otherwise, what is the point of having prefetch_factor.

The purpose of `prefetch_factor` is to buffer against the stochasticity of `DataLoader`. In practice, loading and preprocessing a single batch takes a different amount of time each time (due to locking, scheduling of the worker thread, etc.). A queue size greater than `num_workers + 1` acts as a buffer so that the GPU doesn't stall in case a single batch every now and again takes longer than expected.